# not getting attribute from pageContext object in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm not getting attribute from pageContext object in jsp, Code:

```
<%

    String username =request.getParameter("name");
    if(username!=null){
        //session.setAttribute("sessionUsername", username);
        //application.setAttribute("appUsername", username);
        pageContext.setAttribute( "requestParams",username );
        pageContext.setAttribute("requestScope", username, PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
        pageContext.setAttribute("sessionScope", username, PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
        pageContext.setAttribute("applicationScope", username, PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
    }
    /* String sessionName =(String)session.getAttribute("sessionUsername");

    String applicaString = (String)application.getAttribute("appUsername");
     */
    %>
<%-- <br>
the name is : <%=username%>
<br>
the session name is : <%=sessionName%>
<br>
the application name is : <%=applicaString%>
 --%>
<br>
the request Scope  name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("requestScope")%>

<br>
the sessionScope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("sessionScope")%>

<br>
the appication Scope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("applicationScope")%>

<br>
the page Scope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("requestParams")%>
```

I am getting null in application scope and request scope but this is working fine when I am using setAttribute method having default page scope .

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to this:

```
<%

    String username =request.getParameter("name");
    if(username!=null){
        //session.setAttribute("sessionUsername", username);
        //application.setAttribute("appUsername", username);
        pageContext.setAttribute( "requestParams",username );
        pageContext.setAttribute("requestScope", username, PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
        pageContext.setAttribute("sessionScope", username, PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
        pageContext.setAttribute("applicationScope", username, PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
    }
    /* String sessionName =(String)session.getAttribute("sessionUsername");

    String applicaString = (String)application.getAttribute("appUsername");
     */
    %>
<%-- <br>
the name is : <%=username%>
<br>
the session name is : <%=sessionName%>
<br>
the application name is : <%=applicaString%>
 --%>
<br>
the request Scope  name is : <%=request.getAttribute("requestScope")%>

<br>
the sessionScope name is : <%=session.getAttribute("sessionScope")%>

<br>
the appication Scope name is : <%=application.getAttribute("applicationScope")%>

<br>
the page Scope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("requestParams")%>
```

I changed the following three lines of your code from:

```
the request Scope  name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("requestScope")%>
the sessionScope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("sessionScope")%>
the appication Scope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("applicationScope")%>
```

to:

```
the request Scope  name is : <%=request.getAttribute("requestScope")%>
the sessionScope name is : <%=session.getAttribute("sessionScope")%>
the appication Scope name is : <%=application.getAttribute("applicationScope")%>
```

Comment: another solution is using this code <%=pageContext.getAttribute("requestScope",, PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE)%>
the sessionScope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("sessionScope",PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE)%>
the appication Scope name is : <%=pageContext.getAttribute("applicationScope",PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE)%>

Answer (score 1):

String **keys containing "."** operator are used for maps keys and object property access.

pageContext.setAttribute("my_namespace.VAR_NAME", VAR_NAME);
Parses string as **single token**. But the retrieval wont work because:
items="${my_namespace.VAR_NAME}"
Is parsing it as an object "my_namespace" with **property** "VAR_NAME".

So you cannot namespace out your key-names on the fly. :(

**WORKS**:

```
MY_MAP.put("MY_VAR_NAME",(Object)MY_VAR_NAME);
pageContext.setAttribute("MY_MAP",MY_MAP); 
items="${MY_MAP.MY_VAR_NAME}"
```

**FAILS**:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME", MY_VAR_NAME );
items="${my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME}"
```

**WORKS, but a HACK using unicode "丶" kanji instead of "." :**

```
pageContext.setAttribute("my_namespace丶MY_VAR_NAME");
items="${my_namespace丶MY_VAR_NAME}"
```

It's nice to namespace things out to avoid ambiguity:

**Not Clear:**

---

```
pageContext.setAttribute("AMBIGIOUS_02",AMBIGIOUS_01 );
items="${AMBIGIOUS_02}"
```

---

**Clear, but does not work:**

---

```
pageContext.setAttribute("DOES_NOT_WORK.MyVar",MyVar );
items="${DOES_NOT_WORK.MyVar}"
```

---

Full context of code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<!--meta tag used to be safe on older browsers.-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map"     %>

<%
    String[] MY_VAR_NAME = {"C01","C02","C03"};

    Map<String,Object> MY_MAP =(
    new HashMap<String,Object>());

    pageContext.setAttribute(
        "my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME",MY_VAR_NAME
    );

    MY_MAP.put("MY_VAR_NAME",(Object)MY_VAR_NAME);
    pageContext.setAttribute("MY_MAP",(Object)MY_MAP);
%>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> ForEachSimpleTest </title>
</head>
<body>
    FOR_EACH_STARTS_HERE
    <c:forEach 
        var="current_item" 
        items="${MY_MAP.MY_VAR_NAME}"
    >
        ${current_item} <br/>
    </c:forEach>
    FOR_EACH_ENDS_HERE
</body>
</html>
```

**Other Things I tried:**

---

**KEY:**

- SF : Silently Fails:
- IV : Invalid Expression
- LIT: Doesn't fail, but not what you want.
- ESE: Equal Symbol Expected
- QSE: Quote Symbol Expected

---

```
SF: items="#{my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME}"
SF: items="${my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME}"

SF: items="${my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME}"
SF: items="#{my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME}"

SF: items='${my_namespace[MY_VAR_NAME]}'
SF: items='#{my_namespace[MY_VAR_NAME]}'

SF: items="${param['my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME']}"
SF: items="#{param['my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME']}"

SF: items="${param['sessionScope.MY_VAR_NAME']}"
SF: items="#{param['sessionScope.MY_VAR_NAME']}"

SF: items="${param[my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME]}"
SF: items="#{param[my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME]}"

SF: items="${sessionScope.MY_VAR_NAME}"
SF: items="#{sessionScope.MY_VAR_NAME}"

SF: items='${my_namespace["MY_VAR_NAME"]}'
SF: items='#{my_namespace["MY_VAR_NAME"]}'

IV : items="${${param['my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME']}}"
ESE: items="${'#{param["my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME"]}'}"

QSE: items=${my_namespace["MY_VAR_NAME"]}
QSE: items=#{my_namespace["MY_VAR_NAME"]}

LIT: items="${'my_namespace.MY_VAR_NAME'}"
```

Also Worthy Of Mention:

> Reserved Words: The following words are reserved for the  EL and
>   should not be used as identifiers:
>
> 1. and
> 2. or
> 3. not
> 4. eq
> 5. ne
> 6. lt
> 7. gt
> 8. le
> 9. ge
> 10. true
> 11. false
> 12. null
> 13. instanceof
> 14. empty
> 15. div
> 16. mod

SOURCE:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjddd/index.html

${} vs #{}

> Those expressions that are evaluated  immediately use the ${} syntax. 
>   Expressions whose evaluation is  deferred use the #{} syntax.

SOURCE:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gjddd/

*Stack Used:*

- Notepad++
- Maven
- Tomcat 9
- Heroku